# TimeLimitingCollector Lucene, how to use effectively?

Tags: performance, lucene

I have a Lucene (4.1) index of about 500M documents. I try to build a search interface on it, but I run into some performance issues.

Initially, I show all the hits (paginated) by using a `MatchAllDocumentsQuery`. This search takes long (about 10 seconds). I think this is because of the collector I use, it is one that tries to find the total number of hits `TotalHitCountCollector`.

I would like to be able to time-limit the query, so I found the `TimeLimitingCollector`. Unfortunatly the API docs are a bit shady. It uses a Counter that is not much documented.

Does anyone have experience using the `TimeLimitingCollector` in Lucene 4.x? And if so, are there approaches to get a guesstimate on the total number of hits?

I read the: https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-Artifacts-4.x/javadoc/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TimeLimitingCollector.html and the example, but it is not clear on setting the `Counter` and how to use that in combination with the `numTicks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter can either be thread safe or not - just use the static `Counter.newCounter(boolean threadSafe)` method  to instantiate one that fits you.

Then, let's say we allow 10 ticks and we update ticks in a separate thread. Code should look like this:

```
Counter clock = Counter.newCounter(true);
TimeLimitingCollector collector = new TimeLimitingCollector(c, clock, 10);
collector.setBaseline(0);  
new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      clock.addAndGet(1);  // will kill the indexSearcher.search(...) after 10 ticks (10 seconds)
      Thread.sleep(1000);  // try-catch is necessary here, yes
   }
}.start();
indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
```

I, however, find the above a bit cumbersome. Guava's [TimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(...)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) looks much cleaner even though not native to Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for the Guava tip too!